# how to add a new variable to this ajax script through post

Tags: ajax

I need to be able to send a value from my `PHP` script with a variable called $topid that needs to send that id to getData.php script so i tried like

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Load more data
    $('.load-more').click(function(){
        var topid = Number($('#topid').val());
        var row = Number($('#row').val());
        var allcount = Number($('#all').val());
        row = row + 3;

        if(row <= allcount){
            $("#row").val(row);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'getData.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {row:row},
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $(".load-more").text("Loading...");
                },
                success: function(response){

                    // Setting little delay while displaying new content
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // appending posts after last post with class="post"
                        $(".post:last").after(response).show().fadeIn("slow");

                        var rowno = row + 3;

                        // checking row value is greater than allcount or not
                        if(rowno > allcount){

                            // Change the text and background
                            $('.load-more').text("Hide");
                            $('.load-more').css("background","darkorchid");
                        }else{
                            $(".load-more").text("Load more");
                        }
                    }, 2000);


            }
        });
    }else{
        $('.load-more').text("Loading...");

        // Setting little delay while removing contents
        setTimeout(function() {

            // When row is greater than allcount then remove all class='post' element after 3 element
            $('.post:nth-child(3)').nextAll('.post').remove().fadeIn("slow");

            // Reset the value of row
            $("#row").val(0);

            // Change the text and background
            $('.load-more').text("Load more");
            $('.load-more').css("background","#15a9ce");

        }, 2000);


    }

});
```

});

But somehow it does not seem to be working all I need is the id gets sent to the getData.php script and I then get it through post like $topid = $_POST['topid '];

Answer (score 0):

if you need to sent `topid` to the `getData` change

```
data: {row:row}
```

into something like

```
data: {topid : topid}
```

Comment: i did that too but then i tried to echo it no values are being passed